# Grails Unit test controller with inheritance

Tags: unit-testing, grails, controller

I'm running into an issue when unit testing a controller.  In attempting to test a request, the test incorrectly directs to the wrong method.  Example below, which should clearly illustrate the problem.

**Parent Controller**

```
class ExampleParentController {

    def someMethod = {
        render "FALSE"
    }

    def someMethod(def object)
    {
        render "DEFINITELY FALSE"
    }
}
```

**Child Controller**

```
class ExampleChildController extends ExampleParentController {

    def someMethod = {
        render "TRUE"
    }
}
```

**Test Class**

```
class ExampleChildControllerTests extends ControllerUnitTestCase {

    protected void setUp() {
        super.setUp()
    }

    protected void tearDown() {
        super.tearDown()
    }

    void testSomeMethod() {
        controller.someMethod()
        def result = controller.response.contentAsString
        assertEquals ("TRUE", result)
    }
}
```

I would expect that `controller.someMethod()` would render "TRUE".  This works perfectly when executed while the application is running, as `someMethod(def object)` isn't exposed as an endpoint.  Is there a way to specify which method to execute?

Comment: I found a way around it.  Simply assign the field to a variable, then execute that variable as a normal closure object.  `def clos = controller.someMethod;  clos()`

Comment: Are you using Grails 1.x? Note that for 2.x methods are handled as actions.

Comment: Yes, Grails 1.3.6.  It looks like the closure of someMethod is being treated as a 1 argument method, as when I change to argument structure of `someMethod(def object)` to `someMethod(def object, def another)`, the test passes successfully.  Until I can refactor the code to rename the methods, I am writing my test to just execute the closure block.